# Is there a decimal number slicer in in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi

I'm showing a collection of points on a map in PowerBI and I would like to filter them to show, for example, only points contained between latitude x and y.

I can do that using the filter panel by setting rules on my latitude so it shows only points with latitude greater than x and less than y. However, I'd like to use a visual component to do that. The "Advanced Time Slicer" from the [Visuals Gallery](https://app.powerbi.com/visuals/) seems to do something really similar to what I'd like to achieve however it works with date/time values only.

I think what I would need is a simple and generic slicer that can select a range within a set of decimal values. Is there any component in PowerBI to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Filter pane.  You could add your latitude field to the **Visual Level Filters** well (on the **Visualizations** pane, under **Filters**).  Then a user viewing the report can open the Filters pane and specify a range of numeric values, e.g.

`Show items when the value: 
is greater than
10 
and 
is less than
30`

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for users who are still having this problem. This can be solved from the latest update of Power BI - Here is the corresponding [Link](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/numeric-range-slicer/td-p/281951).

**Step 1.** Duplicate the latitude and longitude column using query editor & give them the datatype of *decimal* number using query editor again.

**Step 2.**  Put these decimal number latitude and longitudes columns that you just created inside the
    *numerical slicer*. [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-slicer-numeric-range) to the official document that talks about Numerical Slicer in PowerBI.

This would save us from creating measures to identify the between values of lat and long.